# map each item in list with a format in make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So I've got this variable:

```
ITEMS = item1 item2
```

and I want a function to do something like this:

```
ITEMS_AFTER := $(fmt prefix{}suffix, $(ITEMS))
```

so it will look like:

```
prefixitem1suffix prefixitem2suffix
```

how would I do it?

I hope i have a shorter way than using `addprefix` combined with `addsuffix`.

Comment: I encourage you to use `addprefix` and `addsuffix`. It is always better to have explicit LISP-like syntax (for your successor programmer), than to use some nifty but obscure special functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach`:

```
ITEMS_AFTER := $(foreach I,$(ITEMS),prefix$Isuffix)
```

or you can use `patsubst`:

```
ITEMS_AFTER := $(patsubst %,prefix%suffix,$(ITEMS))
```

Comment: The latter one should be `$(patsubst %,prefix%suffix,$(ITEMS))` I think.